# Search query containing a variable

Tags: php, mysql

HI I am working on a php mysql project and need some help.

On one of my fields I use a check box to enter a value. The possible options are 9001 14001 and 18001.

If I tick 14001 and 18001 the result that gets stored is 14001,18001.

When I set up a search I have had to set up an if equals for each possible combination. ..not too bad in this case as only 7.

Bit what would I use in an sql query if I wanted to say if (field) contains?

Comment: Can you show you table schema and example data.  It sounds like you may have a bad schema design if you are storing values in comma-separated strings.

Answer (score 0):

The following query would give you all line where field contains 14001.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%14001%'`

But you might want to reconsider the way you store your data to make it faster.
One way to do it is nicely described here:
http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: That would match `14001,18001`, technically it does match the ops criteria of 'contains' but its not exclusive